# c# Compact framework Math.Round up problem

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile-6.5

I am using VS2008 c# , windows mobile 6.5, so I have to use the .Net Compact Framework, the problem is:

When Math.Round(66.05,1) the result is 66 when the correc value should be 66.1
what can I do ? how should I use the round() function

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You should use the overloaded static Math.Round method which takes two arguments:

```
decimal x = Math.Round(2.5555, 2);      // x == 2.56
```

You can read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-math-round-method-set-1/).

The issue with this is that the Mathf.Round method by default use "[ToEven convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.8#System_MidpointRounding_ToEven)"  There is an example using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero that will give you the result you expect

Comment: try with my example,..  it goes down, no  up,... thats the problem

Comment: Oh I understand, well the Mathf.Round method by default use "ToEven convention" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.8#System_MidpointRounding_ToEven
There is an example using MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero that will give you the result you expect.

Comment: You should update your answer with the `.ToEven` answer. You would get the accept on that rather than downvotes.